# Finding $\operatorname{Tor}(G)$ for the Heisenberg group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, torsion-groups

The Heisenberg group $G$ over the field $k$ is the subgroup of $GL_{3}(k)$ defined by the matrices of the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & x & z\\
0 & 1 & y \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\qquad (x, y, z \in k)$$
Find  $\operatorname{Tor}(G)$.

How can I find  $\operatorname{Tor}(G)$? could anyone help me please?

Comment: By $\mathrm{Tor}(G)$, do you mean finite order elements?

Comment: @qualcuno yes other than the identity

Comment: I think that it's more natural to assume $Tor(G)$ to include the identity. This makes valid the fact that the set of torsion elements in every nilpotent group, is a subgroup, this makes valid that under every homomorphism $f:G\to H$, $f(Tor(G))\subset Tor(H)$, etc. Of course "$G$ torsion-free" means that $Tor(G)=\{1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify (by induction) that $$\begin{pmatrix}1&x&z\\0&1&y\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}1&nx&\frac{1}{2}n^2xy-\frac{1}{2}nxy+nz\\0&1&ny\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

I assume that by $\text{Tor}(G)$ you mean $\text{Tor}(G)=\{A\in G\mid A^m=I_3 \text{ for some }m\geq 1\}$? If so, the above depends on the characteristic of your field (and I probably am using bad notation if said characteristic were $2$!).

**EDIT:** Let's do the induction. For $n=1$, there is nothing to prove, so assume that equality holds for $n\geq 1$. Then
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&x&z\\0&1&y\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}^{n+1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&x&z\\0&1&y\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&nx&\frac{1}{2}n^2xy-\frac{1}{2}nxy+nz\\0&1&ny\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&(n+1)x&(\frac{1}{2}n^2xy-\frac{1}{2}nxy+nz)+nxy+z\\0&1&(n+1)y\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Note that $(\frac{1}{2}n^2xy-\frac{1}{2}nxy+nz)+nxy+z=(\frac{1}{2}(n+1)^2xy-\frac{1}{2}(n+1)xy+(n+1)z)$. This shows the induction argument.

Comment: How did you know the characteristic of my field?

Comment: Just for completion's sake, by your argument every element is of torsion if $\mathrm{char} K \neq 0,2$. Likewise, if $k$ has characteristic zero, then no non-trivial element is of torsion.

Comment: Why specifically $0,2$?

Comment: How can I do the induction? it is hard.

Comment: @Smart20 Because otherwise $1/2$ does not make sense as an element of $k$. For example, if $k = F_p$ the field of $p$ elements with $p$ prime, then the Heisenberg group for $p > 2$ has all elements of order $p$ whereas $\mathrm{Heis}(2) \simeq \mathbb{D}_4$, the dihedral group.

Comment: I did not understand what you said in the last comment very much

Comment: Should not the $m$ be $n$ in your definition for $\text{Tor(G)}$?

Comment: I don't know the characteristic of your field. I'm saying the answer depends on the characteristic of the field $k$. If for example $k=\mathbb{C}$, the above argument yields that $\text{Tor}(G)=\{I_3\}$. If the characteristic of the field $k$ is some prime $p$ (and assume for the moment that $p\neq 2$), then $A^p=0$ by the above formula. In the special case that $p=2$, dividing by $2$ does not make sense as you're really just dividing by zero! You'll have to look at that case separately.

Comment: Also, no, the $m$ should not be $n$ in my definition. I explicitly used $m$ as to avoid any confusion with the above statement involving $n$.

Comment: Why $A^p = 0$? and not $I_{3}$

Comment: That's a bad habbit, I meant $A^p=I_3$, the identity element (I write zero because I think of this as the neutral element, but I should write $1$ or something similar as the operation is a multiplication).

Comment: If the characteristic is 2 this group is also torsion. Indeed it consists of matrices $I+N$ with $N^3=0$. So $(1+N)^4=1+4N+6N^2=1$.